# Why can we only notify one additional user of a comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments

When we make a comment, why are we only permitted to notify one additional user? Sometimes there may be good reason to notify two or more users. What's the harm in that?

Comment: Because [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176040/284336).

Comment: And [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85771/is-single-comment-to-notify-several-users-a-reasonable-idea)

Comment: @Catija I see. This has been requested, and no *good* reason is given for the limitation, but it's not going to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: I agree this is a good idea. At least 2 or 3 would be helpful. +1

Comment: Regardless of it being a good idea or not, it's not a Sci-Fi only issue and it's already been addressed several times over on Meta.SE.